# How to get selected checkbox in a controller using model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i am trying to get the value of selected check-box using model but not able to get as i want ;

Below is the table image [image]

below is my code for this VIEW

[image]

And below is the code for result.I get null value

[image]

And below is my model declaration

```
public class RoleDetail
  {
    [Key]
    public int RoleDetailID { get; set; }

    public bool IsCreate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
    public bool IsView { get; set; }
    public bool IsEdit { get; set; }
    public bool IsDownload { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public Int32 UserTypeId { get; set; }
}
public enum ControllerName
{
    Account, Candidate, Career, ChooseUs, ContactUs, DocumentType, Employee, Gallery, GalleryType, GetTouch, Home, JobCategory, Jobs, Portfolio, ResumeUpload, RoleDetail, Services, User, UserRoleType

}
```

Comment: Why do you expect this to work? Where is your model type declaration?

Comment: @leppie just edit the question with Model declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be creating `RoleDetail` in the view. In the GET method create a `List<RoleDetail>`, populate it with the objects you want to display and return it to the view.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  List<RoleDetail> model = new List<RoleDetail>();
  // populate the collection, for example
  foreach(var name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(ControllerName)))
  {
    model.Add(new RoleDetail()
    {
      ControllerName = name,
      IsCreate = true // etc
    });
  }  
  return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<RoleDetail> model)
{
}
```

View

```
@model List<RoleDetail>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ControllerName) // needed for postback
    @Html.DisplayFor( => m.ControllerName)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsCreate)
    ....
  }
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Side notes

1. Do not try to override the `name` (or `value`) attribute. The html
   helper set these correctly for model binding (and in any case you
   were only setting it to the value the helper generated anyway)
2. The reason the `foreach` loop does not work is your generating
   duplicate `name` attributes (and also invalid html due to duplcate
   `id` attributes). The `for` loop correctly generates the correct
   names with indexers (e.g. `<input name="[0].IsCreate " ..>`, `<input
   name="[1].IsCreate " ..>` etc.
3. You don't appear to be rendering controls for all of you model
   properties so use a view model containing only those properties you
   need to display/edit. [What is a view model in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)
4. You have `public enum ControllerName` so I suspect property
   `ControllerName` in `RoleDetail` should be `public ControllerName ControllerName { get; set; }`?

And in future, post the code, not an image of it!

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `foreach` loop in your view with a `for`:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
{
    ...
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => lst[i].IsCreate)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => lst[i].IsView)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => lst[i].IsDelete)
    ...
}
```

For this to work make sure that the variable you are iterating over is an `IList<T>` or `T[]`.

Also your controller action argument should be named accordingly:

```
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<RoleDetail> lst)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: ControllerName(it's variable) isComing from  from different model.That's why i need to create a RoleDetail object in view .Please check the view Image in the question